# Retina.js makes image not displayed on retina screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Retina.js included to my html body and for some reason if page is viewed on retina screen the logo is not displayed, eventhough there is logo@2x.png image in /images/ folder.

```
<img title="Rahapuu.ee" alt="logo" src="images/logo.png">

<script src="js/retina.js"></script>
```

And when looked on iPad it gives this in return:

[imgur picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkrrI.jpg)

Retina.js is the one from retinajs.com without editing.

Comment: what image is it trying to load there?

Comment: image is the logo. I have 2 images in images/ folder. logo.png and logo@2x.png